# Trying to delete a key/value pair from JSON within a list

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

[image]

```
def loop_through_list_keys_and_update_or_delete(body_dict, list_key, key_to_manipulate, update_or_delete):
    request_body = body_dict
    try:

        for keys in request_body[list_key]:
            for key, value in keys.items():
                if key == key_to_manipulate:
                    if update_or_delete == 'delete':
                        del request_body[key]
```

Hi all!  Relatively new to Python, so please be gentle and I definitely appreciate your help!  In the attached picture are my run time values.  Basically what I am trying to do is delete a specific (but one that changes) key/value pair.  The request_body is my json that I've read in.

I am looping on the list 'fxTransactions' and the only keys it is getting are financialTransaction and transactionRefId.  In this case, I need to get to the request_body[fxTransactions][0][financialTransaction][rule]  field that is within financialTransaction and delete it and its value.  But I can't send this as a variable to the delete as you can't combine the list name with the keys in a variable.  I can't seem to figure out how to get to this field and delete it.  Note that the field/value pair to delete is dynamic so I will not always know which one I want to delete (could be debtor, creditor, etc).  I'd also like to use this code for other lists, if possible, so trying not to hard-code.  But I can if there is no other way.

Thank you in advance!

Here is code that works to do what I'm trying to do, but I'm trying to come up with a way to make it cleaner and reusable:

```
index_key_int = int(index_key)
split_key = key.split(".")
keys_numb = len(split_key)
if keys_numb == 5:
    del request_body[list_key][index_key_int][split_key[0]][split_key[1]][split_key[2]][split_key[3]][
        split_key[4]]
if keys_numb == 4:
    del request_body[list_key][index_key_int][split_key[0]][split_key[1]][split_key[2]][split_key[3]]
if keys_numb == 3:
    del request_body[list_key][index_key_int][split_key[0]][split_key[1]][split_key[2]]
elif keys_numb == 2:
    del request_body[list_key][index_key_int][split_key[0]][split_key[1]]
elif keys_numb == 1:
    del request_body[list_key][index_key_int][split_key[0]]
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, not images.

Comment: Please read [why you should not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: `key` is a key of the `keys` dictionary, but you're deleting it from `request_body`.

Comment: Why do you need a loop? You can just use `if key_to_manipulate in keys:`

Comment: I've posted the code, along with code that does what I'm trying to do in a different/not clean way, and more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop instead of hard-coding all the nested indexing.

```
obj = request_body[list_key][index_key_int]
for key in split_key[:-1]:
    obj = obj[key]
del obj[split_key[-1]]
```

The `for` loop dives down into the nested dictionaries. Then it deletes the element with the final key.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This works great for delete!  For setting a value, can I just do obj[split_key[-1]] = value ?

Comment: Yes, of course. In fact, the question I derived the code from was for doing that.

Comment: Fantastic!  Both parts worked and I learned a lot from this.  I really appreciate it!